# All possible Combinations using Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have an easy looking mathematical problem. 
Here is an array.

> Array = { 1, 2, 3 }

Need all possible combinations from the above mentioned array elements which will make the total sum = 5.

> Solution:   { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1  }  { 1, 1, 1, 2 }  { 1, 2, 2 } { 2, 3 } { 1, 1, 3 }

**Note: You may use any array element any number of times provided the sum should be 5.**

```
        int weight = 5;
        List<int> weights = new List<int>() { 1, 2 ,3};


   void function1(int weight,List<int> weights, List<List<int>> combinationlist)
    { 
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.Count; i++)
        {
            if (weight % weights[i] == 0)
            {
                int num = weight / weights[i];
                List<int> mylist = new List<int>();
                for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
                {
                    mylist.Add(weights[i]);

                }

                if (!combinationlist.Contains(mylist))
                    combinationlist.Add(mylist);
            }


        }


    }
```

Now the above function generated the easy combination of {1,1,1,1,1} Solution.

```
    void function2(int weight, List<int> weights, List<List<int>> combinationlist)
    {
        int i = weights.Count - 1;
        Stack<int> mystack = new Stack<int>();
        List<int> combinationarray = new List<int>();


        foreach (var x in weights)
            mystack.Push(x);

        for (;i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (weight <= weights[i])
                mystack.Pop();  
        }


        int remainder = 0;


        if (weight % mystack.Peek() != 0)
            remainder = weight % mystack.Peek();

            int quotient = weight / mystack.Peek();

            combine(combinationlist,combinationarray,mystack,quotient,remainder);


    }
```

Combine function

```
void combine(List<List<int>>combinations,List<int>combination,Stack<int> mystack,int quotient, int remweight)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < quotient; i++)
        {

            combination.Add(mystack.Peek());
        }

        if (remweight > 1)
            remweight = remweight - mystack.Peek() * quotient;
        else if (remweight == 0)
        {
            if (!combinations.Contains(combination))
                combinations.Add(combination);

            return;

        }

        else
            return;

        while (mystack.Peek() > remweight )
        {
            if (mystack.Count != 0)
                mystack.Pop();
        }

        quotient = remweight / mystack.Peek();


combine(combinations, combination, mystack, quotient, remweight);


        }
```

With all that work . I could only get two solutions {2,1,1,1} {1,1,1,1,1}.

Comment: What you tried ? What errors do you get ? SO is not here to do your homework :)

Comment: Have you made any attempts towards solving this?  What considerations have you taken so far?  We're not here to just solve problems for you, show your effort and where you went wrong and we'll help push you onto the right track

Comment: Part of a bigger problem. I have tried. Not getting all possible answers.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so we know where you stand on your problem.

Comment: Why is this tagged as 'dynamic programming'? Is dynamic programmig explicitly required? Can all numbers in the input assumed to be positive? Is 0 permitted?

Comment: Because this was part of knapsack problem which I was doing. unbounded  Knapsack which requires dynamic programming.

Comment: Only numbers which are part of array are permitted. 0 is not permitted.

Comment: This is a well known dynamic-programming problem called the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: Do you need just the total number of solutions?  Or do you need an enumeration of solutions?

Comment: Solution like  {1,1,1,1,1}{2,2,1} ...

Comment: Why down voted?

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide an answer in python since it illustrates the algorithm well. Python is nearly like pseudo-code for such problems.

```
# curr: a temporary list that is used only for printing the result
# arr: the list of input values
# val: the number we want to sum to
# currval: the number used so far (that will be the maximum number used so far)
def recursive_combos(curr, arr, val, currval):
    for item in arr:
        if item < currval:
            continue
        if val - item < 0:
            return
        if val - item == 0:
            print curr + [item]
            continue
        recursive_combos(curr + [item], arr, val - item, item)
    return

def combos(arr, val):
    recursive_combos([], sorted(arr), 5, min(arr) - 1)

combos([3, 1, 2], 5)
```

Answer:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 3]
```

This is a basic illustration of recursion and I think the code is mostly self-explanatory.

The key things to note in this solution are:

1. The array needs to be sorted to help eliminate duplicates
2. The 4th parameter needs to be present to eliminate duplicates. I think you'll find it a useful exercise to eliminate it and try the code. There is likely a cleaner way to do it rather than pass the 4th parameter and you could try that out.
3. This does not use memoization that is another key-component of dynamic programming. That will need to store the results somewhere for a value and look up the answer. It can easily be plugged in though.

Answer (score 0):

Following method simplifies and gets all solutions (code is in Racket programming language). Comments explain the procedure being done:

```
(define L '(0 1 2 3))       ; ADD 0 TO THE LIST; 

(define outl
  (for*/list (   ; TRY ALL COMBINATIONS CHOOSING 5 NUMBERS FROM ABOVE LIST;
                 ; SINCE THAT IS MAXIMUM NUMBER OF ELEMENTS THAT CAN ADD UP TO 5;
                 ; REPETITION IS ALLOWED;
              (i L)
              (j L)
              (k L)
              (m L)
              (n L)
              #:when (= 5 (+ i j k m n)))   ; USE COMBINATION ONLY IF SUM IS 5;
  (remove* (list 0)                         ; REMOVE 0s FROM THIS COMBINATION;
           (sort (list i j k m n) <))))     ; SORT COMBINATION;

(remove-duplicates outl)                    ; REMOVE DUPLICATES FROM LIST;
```

Output is a list of answer lists:

```
'((2 3) (1 1 3) (1 2 2) (1 1 1 2) (1 1 1 1 1))
```

Another solution is using recursion to keep adding all elements till sum is reached (or exceeded):

```
(define L '(1 2 3))
(define desired_sum 5)

(define anslist '())       ; solutions will be added to this list;

(let loop ((ol '()))       ; start with an empty list;
  (for ((i L))             ; try adding each element and see if desired sum is reached; 
    (cond
      [(= desired_sum (apply + (cons i ol)))  ; desired sum reached
       (set! anslist                          ; add sorted solution to anslist;
             (cons (sort (cons i ol) <)       ; sorting needed to identify duplicates later;
                   anslist))]        
      [(> desired_sum (apply + (cons i ol)))  ; total is less than desired sum
       (loop (cons i ol))]                    ; so loop again to add more elements;
      )))                    ; discard (no looping) if desired sum is exceeded;

(remove-duplicates anslist)  ; print after removing duplicate solutions;
```

Output:

```
'((2 3) (1 1 3) (1 2 2) (1 1 1 2) (1 1 1 1 1))
```